# How to re-populate select options for angular primeng dropdown

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

I have a form that has a dropdown using primeng components like below:

```
    <p-dropdown 
          [style]="{'width': '100%', 'border': 'none'}" 
          [options]="categories | toSelectItem" 
          name="product.category.id"
          class="primeng-custom-dropdown">
               <ng-template let-category pTemplate="item">
                   <div style="position: relative;">
                     <img src="{{category.image}}" style="width:24px;margin: 0 10px 0"/>
                     <div style="font-size:14px;display:inline;">{{category.label}}</div>
                   </div>
              </ng-template>
   </p-dropdown>
```

When the form is already loaded and categories are already shown, I have another component in the form that adds a new category. I would also like to have that new category added to the primeng dropdown.

my ts component looks like below:

```
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
 categories: Category[];
 constructor(
   private api: ApiService
 ) {}

   ngOnInit() {
     this.getCategories();
   }

   getCategories(): void {
      this.api.getCategories()
        .subscribe(categories => { 
          this.categories = categories;
       });
   }
}
```

When I call the getCategories() again in a separate function, the list of categories in the dropdown doesn't seem to get the updated list. How do I make the list categories in the primeng dropdown component be updated as well?

Comment: Push to this.categories then save the new categories in the server.

Comment: Hi @ChauTran I am already doing that, in fact when I refresh the page, the new category is shown in the dropdown.

Comment: @ChauTran, you were right, I just realised what you mean. It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per @Chautran comment. I subscribed to the dialog which adds the new category and return the created category to the main component where the dialog is triggered

```
addCategory() {
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CategoryFormDialogComponent, {
    position: {
      top: '80px',
    }
  });
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(category => {
    this.categories.push(category); // As per @Chautran
    this.getCategories();
  });
}
```

Comment: This does not address the data binding issue with PrimeNg Dropdown and is not a solution for that problem.